# Rails way to COUNT the nr of records in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**.

I have a **model** called `UsersCar`:

```
class UsersCar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This **model** mapped to a database table `users_cars`, which only contains two columns : `user_id`, `car_id`.

I would like to use **Rails** way to count the number of `car_id` **where** `user_id=3`. I konw in plain SQL query I can achieve this by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_cars WHERE user_id=3;
```

Now, I would like to get it by **Rails** way, I know I can do:

```
UsersCar.count()
```

but how can I put the `...where user_id=3` clause in **Rails** way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#calculations), you can pass conditions to the `count()` method. For example:

```
UsersCar.count(:conditions => ["user_id = ?", 3])
```

will generates:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM users_cars WHERE (user_id = 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the User object, you could do

```
user.cars.size
```

or

```
user.cars.count
```

Another way would be to do:

```
UserCar.find(:user_id => 3).size
```

And the last way that I can think of is the one mentioned above, i.e. 'UserCar.count(conditions)'.

Answer (score 1):

With the [belogngs to association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association), you get several "magic" methods on the parent item to reference its children.

In your case:

```
users_car = UsersCar.find(1) #=>one record of users_car with id = 1.
users_car.users              #=>a list of associated users.
users_car.users.count        #=>the amount of associated users.
```

However, I think you are understanding the associations wrong, based on the fact that your UsersCar is named awkwardly.

It seems you want

- User has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
- Car  has_and_belongs_to_manu :users

Please read abovementioned guide on associations if you want to know more about many-to-many associations in Rails.

Comment: I am just simply asking how to use Rails model.count() to get the same result as SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id=3... And you understand my question in a wrong way, because the users_cars table is only a linked table to link users table and cars table.

Comment: this is indeed the rails way, and produces exaclty the sql you want. but you can of course use just `UsersCar.where(:user_id => 3).count()`

Comment: @Leem.fin, since you specifically asked for *the rails way*, I assumed you wanted to know how to count items based on their associations and not "simply how to get the SELECT COUNT... query fired. Hence my explanation on how to do associations and how to reference their children. If you run my code in the rails console, you will see that it queries the database with your exact requested query, though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the way to count with condition:

```
UsersCar.count(:condition=>"user_id=3")
```